# Prevent extra queries after performing join fetch when referencedColumn not matching the joinColumn

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql, jpql, hibernate-mapping

I have these entities where some values of ref_b may not match any row in table b.

```
class A {

  @Id 
  @Column(name = id)
  Long id; 

  @Column(name = "column_b")
  private String ref_b;
  
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "column_b", referencedColumnName = "non_primary_column_in_b", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private B b;
}


class B {

  @Id 
  @Column(name = id)
  Long id; 

  @NaturalId 
  @Column(name = "non_primary_column_in_b")
  String naturalId
}
```

When calling this repository method extra queries are generated for every row in A with mismatch between column_b and non_primary_column_in_b.

```
@Query("""
      from A a
      left join fetch a.b
      """)
  List<A> findAllA()
```

Is there a way to prevent the extra queries?

I tried using a simple join fetch instead of join fetch but retrieving the A rows with values that don't match the B table is a requirement.

I tried to use @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) and  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY), but that didn't work either.

Also I added @JsonIgnore to the @ManyToOne relation but the still extra queries are being generated by hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the extra queries when fetching entities with mismatched values in the join condition, you can use a left join fetch with a subquery to filter out the entities with mismatched values. You can modify your repository method to achieve .

```
@Query("""
    from A a
    left join fetch a.b b
    where a.ref_b = b.naturalId or b.naturalId is null
""")
List<A> findAllA();
```

In this modified query, the left join fetch is performed between A and B, and the condition a.ref_b = b.naturalId or b.naturalId is null is added to filter out the entities where the ref_b value does not match any row in table B. This way, the mismatched entities will still be retrieved, but without triggering extra queries for each mismatched row.

Additionally, you mentioned that you tried using @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) and @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) without success. Please note that changing the fetch type alone won't prevent the extra queries in this case. The issue lies in the join condition and the mismatched values. Therefore, the modified query with the appropriate condition is required.

Regarding the usage of @JsonIgnore, it is primarily used for controlling JSON serialization and deserialization. It won't affect the extra queries generated by Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've tried your approach an the extra queries are still being generated. 

The naturalId in B table should always be non null.